# How server handle REST API path parameters

Tags: rest

When design REST API, you can have

GET /userinfo?id=124,

you can also make the parameter part of the path:

GET /userinfo/124.

I understand on the server side, how the server get the parameter for the first case. But I do not understand how server can get the userid parameter in the second case: /userinfo/124.

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand on the server side, how the server get the parameter for the first case. But I do not understand how server can get the userid parameter in the second case: /userinfo/124.

Exactly the same way: the server parses the string.

Which is to say, in exactly the same way that we can take a string, and break it up into a path part and a query part, and then break the query part into a sequence of key and value pairs, we can also take the path part and break it up into a sequence of path segments.

It might help to look at [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), which describes URI templates, or to look at how the Java annotation javax.ws.rs.Path is used in [routing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html), but under the covers it is all just string manipulation plus conventions for finding the right String to X parsing function.